# Sharing hash objects between SAS sessions

Tags: parallel-processing, sas, hashtable

I've got one extremely large dataset and one moderately large dataset. I want to hash merge the smaller one onto the larger one. I only need to keep a small proportion of rows/columns from the resulting merge, so the approach I've used is to fire up several parallel sessions using SAS/CONNECT and have each of them deal with a separate range of rows from the extremely large dataset. When each of the parallel hash merges has finished, I append the pieces together.

The problem I'm facing with this approach is that every parallel session needs to keep its own copy of the moderately large dataset in memory, so the amount of available system memory quickly becomes a performance bottleneck when the number of sessions scales up. Is there a way for one SAS session to access another session's hash object, or some other approach that would give the same sort of performance benefit without requiring 1 in-memory copy per parallel session?

The only thing I can think of would be to copy the moderately large dataset to a ramdisk, and change the hash merges to index merges. Are there any other options worth considering?

I've tried Reeza's suggestion of using a format merge based on a format definition stored in a common library used by all the parallel sessions, but I've found that each session ends up requiring additional memory in exactly the same way as a hash merge. This is not reported in the fullstimer statistics for individual procs or data steps using the format, but it is obvious when signing off the session or from using appropriate OS tools.

Comment: Is your merge/look up a one to one of some kind? Is PROC FORMAT another option?

Comment: It's 1-1 or many-1. I don't think formats will help here as each session has to load its own copy into memory.

Comment: Isn't that exactly why a format may help? If it's already in the library/compiled I don't believe there's a huge overhead to creating/loading the format.

Comment: Ok, I'll test and report back. I suspect that the format is still ultimately copied into each session's memory even if they all load it from the same library, but it's worth a try.

Comment: No joy, unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: What if instead of splitting your extremely large dataset by row number, you split it by your ID value (quartiles or quintiles or whatever).  Then you could split your moderately large dataset the same way. So each child session would only build a hash table for a subset of the moderately large dataset.

Comment: @Quentin - one nice property of splitting by row number is that I can use views that each only ever have to read a small fraction of the extremely large dataset, with no duplication of reads. Splitting by anything else would dramatically increase the amount of reads / writes required as it is not sorted by the keys used for the merge.

Comment: Sure, but it's all tradeoffs, the balancing of which would depend on your environment.  If you have the work library space, you could use just one read/write of the big dataset to split it by ID into separate datasets rather than views, and one read/write of the moderate dataset to split it.  There's obviously cost there, but benefit of reduced memory need for child session hash tables.  Also consider adding indexing on ID, which could allow you to keep the view approach and still split the hash table by ID.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, the problem is that you are unable to do this in a single session because you can't load the extremely large table into memory.

I've had this issue before and figured out a workaround (although somewhat complex) that allows you to effectively remove the memory limitation of hash objects while minimizing overhead.

The basic premise is to sort your extremely large table, and your small table by the 'key' first (this is the only piece of overhead).  Even though these are now sorted, using indexes are still much slower than hashing on these extremely large tables (my large table was ~1B rows and my smaller table was in the millions of rows although it could be any size).

Next you want to calculate a bunch of metadata about your large table.  The idea is to split it into enough buckets so that each individual bucket is small enough to fit into memory, and each bucket contains sequential data (taken care of by the earlier sort).  You also want to make sure that a given key only exists within a single bucket.

For example, if I had one billion rows, and I know I can fit 1 million rows into memory at a time, I would calculate metadata that looks something like this:

```
bucket first_obs last_obs    key_min    key_max
====== ========= =========== ========== ===========
1              1    10000000          a         a23
2       10000001    20000000        a24         c19
...
...
100    999000001  1000000000    z394883    zzzzzzzz
```

The final step is similar to a regular hashtable/datastep process. Initially you will load the first bucket into the hashtable, and each iteration of the datastep check to see if your key value means you need to load the next bucket.  If so, delete the hash table (using `ht.delete()`) and load the next bucket into it.  You can do that using code something along the lines of:

```
declare hash ht&cnt(dataset:"largeds(firstobs=&first_obs obs=&last_obs)");
```

Because you are deleting the hashtable before loading the next set of data you will not run out of memory.  You will only ever need to load each bucket into memory once, and you will only need to walk through the smaller dataset once so the approach is very efficient (especially if both sets of data are already sorted by the key).  There is also no limit to the number of hashtables you can define in a datastep, so my macro code may have resolved to declaring 100+ hash tables (only 1 would ever contain data at a time though).

You will most likely want to build this datastep within a macro to make use of the metadata easily.

A bit of a hassle, but worth the effort if you need something very efficient.  It'd be nice if SAS added this kind of functionality themselves...